# How to use SQL result with left Join to iterate over the rows in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, join

I have used left join in PHP & MySQL earlier but I am stuck in a scenario of my new project in C#

I have a table of users like:-

```
id name
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Next table of images of users like:-

```
id image
1  a1.jpg
1  a2.jpg
1  a3.jpg
2  b1.jpg
3  c1.jpg
3  c2.jpg
```

Now when I do the join I get result:-

```
id name image
1   a    a1.jpg
1   a    a2.jpg
1   a    a3.jpg
2   b    b1.jpg
and so on
```

Now on webpage(ASP.net) I have to show the result of all the users with all their images in a single page

```
a ----- a1.jpg, a2.jpg, a3.jpg
b ----- b2.jpg
c ----- c1.jpg, c2.jpg
```

And earlier what I was doing is without using joins, I used to load users, then in dt.read() another inner query to load image from other table but it was making many queries...

Can any one guide me to the best way???

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySql?

Comment: SQL Server with asp.net

Answer (score 0):

Try This:-

```
--create table tblUser
--(
--Id INT,
--Name VARCHAR(100)
--)

--create table tblImage
--(
--Id INT,
--ImagePath VARCHAR(100)
--)

--INSERT INTO tblUser
--SELECT 1, 'a'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 2, 'b'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 3, 'c'


--INSERT INTO tblImage
--SELECT 1,'a1.jpg'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 1,'a2.jpg'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 1,'a3.jpg'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 2,'b1.jpg'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 3,'c1.jpg'
--UNION ALL
--SELECT 3,'c2.jpg'
```

ANSWER :-

```
SELECT DISTINCT Users.Id,Users.Name,ImagePath = 
    STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ImagePath 
           FROM tblImage ImageTable
           WHERE Images.Id = ImageTable.Id
           FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
FROM tblUser Users
JOIN tblImage Images ON Users.Id = Images.Id
```

Comment: That worked fine....but it is also too slow...taking around 8 seconds to return top 10 rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SQL function.
Suppose you have this two tables named: Users, Pics
create this function:

```
create function GetPics(@UserId int)
returns nvarchar(max)
as 
begin
    declare rs cursor local fast_forward readonly for
        select image from Pics where Id = @UserId

    declare @pics nvarchar(max), @pic nvarchar(255)
    fetch next from rs into @pic
    while @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
    begin
        if(len(@pics) = 0) 
            set @pics = @pic
        else
            set @pics = @pics + ', '+@pic

        fetch next from rs into @pic
    end

    close rs
    deallocate rs
    return @pics
end
```

After you can use it in this way:

```
select u.Id, dbo.GetPics(u.Id) as Images
from   Users
```

Please do not use this for large data but only if you need to retrieve a short list of results. I always not recommend cursors usage.

Hope this can help,

Comment: Thank you Roberto, even I prefer not using cursors but will try it

Answer (score 0):

Due to performance issues I haven't use any of the given methods as I have commented on them, its taking more than 8-10 seconds to return a simple top 10 result. So I have done it another way...

1. Get the sql result in dataset using join
2. Using linq into the asp.net

Time taken - 0.3 Seconds(at max)